# Use of Local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar

Tags: java

What is the use of these jars:

```
Local_policy.jar
US_export_policy.jar
```

I have seen other SO questions where they are asking how to upgrade. My question is what's the use of these jars. It seems they come as a violation in open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THEY ARE OBSOLETE** (at least as separate added files)

They *were* used in an optional, and (nominally) geographically restricted, patch to versions of Sun-then-Oracle Java before late 2017, to enable (symmetric) ciphers with strength of more than 128 bits, which were disabled in the basic distribution packages in a lingering after-effect of conformity to US export regulations from the 1990s. No such patch was ever needed for OpenJDK, once that was released (which only started after the 'crypto thaw'), but in its early years it wasn't widely supported and sometimes not consistently available, so many people continued using the Oracle/Sun versions -- and many Stack Overflow questions and/or answers (both Stack Overflow and others like security.SX and Super User and Server Fault) were written for that case. Since Stack Overflow doesn't automatically delete or even deprecate old content, it remains available.

For the official details (of the versions that still have any support, even paid) see https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html .

IBM has long had its own implementation of Java, especially the cryptographic parts, and had a similar (but not the same) set of policy jars; I don't know if they still do, since I no longer have IBM systems running Java. In any case, Stack Overflow questions and answers for IBM Java are rare.

The 'openness' of the original Sun-centered model for Java was somewhat controversial for years, until finally settled by the establishment of OpenJDK. If you want to discuss that, it probably belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am using Java 8, so does it still qualify to be obsolete? If so, then what options come out of the box (that is, by JDK itself)?

Comment: If you're using Oracle 8u161 up (as my link says, which are after late 2017 as I said), the unlimited-policy patch is obsolete; the install already has the unlimited policy. If OpenJDK 8 at any update, no patch is or ever was needed, as I said. If IBM Java 8, I don't know, as I said.