# local_policy.jar in JDK 20 and JRE 1.8

Tags: java

I'm trying to perform a transformation on Pentaho 9.3 using a database on my machine (localhost).

Whenever I try to run, it returns the following error: `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity`

Searching for the error, I found this question on SO: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301407/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-javax-crypto-jcesecur)

> Make sure the following files on executing JRE is NOT corrupted/modified/deleted.
> jre\lib\security\local_policy.jar
> jre\lib\security\US_export_policy.jar

However, I didn't find either of these files. I have searched on both JDK 17 and 20 and JRE 1.8 files, all fresh installations.

What should I do?

Adding stack trace for a greater context:

```
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - Running transformation using the Kettle execution engine
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - Launching transformation [Transf 01 Importa Dados 2005 para DS]...
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Transf 01 Importa Dados 2005 para DS - Dispatching started for transformation [Transf 01 Importa Dados 2005 para DS]
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Table output]
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.nextSpi(SecretKeyFactory.java:299)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:117)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:164)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.ScramMechanisms.saltedPassword(ScramMechanisms.java:155)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.ScramFunctions.saltedPassword(ScramFunctions.java:59)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ClientFinalProcessor.<init>(ScramSession.java:196)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ClientFinalProcessor.<init>(ScramSession.java:163)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ServerFirstProcessor.clientFinalProcessor(ScramSession.java:130)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator.processServerFirstMessage(ScramAuthenticator.java:147)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:778)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:191)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:589)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:481)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:389)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:360)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.init(TableOutput.java:533)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:69)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: http [in thread "Thread-10"]
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:249)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:549)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.isTransformationAvailable(SSLCipher.java:477)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<init>(SSLCipher.java:466)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<clinit>(SSLCipher.java:90)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:65)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:337)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:550)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1988)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getDefaultConstructor(Provider.java:2019)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf(Provider.java:1933)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:1941)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1916)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:51)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.versionchecker.VersionChecker.buildHttpClient(VersionChecker.java:413)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.versionchecker.VersionChecker.performCheck(VersionChecker.java:367)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.lifecycle.pdi.VersionCheckerListener$1.run(VersionCheckerListener.java:88)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Table output.0 -  ... 1 more
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Transf 01 Importa Dados 2005 para DS - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : Step [Table output.0] failed to initialize!
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : Transf 01 Importa Dados 2005 para DS: preparing transformation execution failed
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - We failed to initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin!
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - 
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon - 
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:1295)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon -   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph$30.run(TransGraph.java:4281)
2023/08/27 01:09:37 - Spoon -   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Comment: First time seeing `%3A+Could+not+initialize+class+`, but I've seen `NoClassDefFoundError` be thrown when the static initialization of a class failed (e.g. an exception being thrown). Those files noted in the linked duplicates may have new names now (since the answer is dated 2015, which was Java 8-11 era). More information regarding the error (e.g. a stack trace) would be helpful, or some type of reproducible example. Without those debugging details, we're left shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho 9.3 is supported on Java 11; see [What's new in Pentaho 9.3](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.3/What%27s_new_in_Pentaho_9.3).

What you are seeing is due to your attempting to run it on Java 20.  In Java 17, the security manager framework has been deprecated (see https://openjdk.org/jeps/411), and in Java 18 they started the process of dismantling it and removing it from the OpenJDK code base.

It *appears* that Pentaho 9.3 startup depends on the security manager and/or on the obsolete<sup>1</sup> crypto export policy JAR files that apparently have been removed<sup>2</sup>; see [Use of Local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221732).  You didn't provide full stacktraces so we can't diagnose this fully.

<sup>1 - Full strength crypto support is now enabled by default in all current builds of Java 8 and later.  The policy JARs have been obsolete for over 5 years; see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8170157.

2 - I couldn't track down precisely when they were removed.</sup>

---

> What should I do?

My recommendation would be to use Java 11 until the vendor releases a Pentaho version that *they say* supports Java 17 LTS or the soon to be released Java 21 LTS.

Trying to get Pentaho (any version!) to work on a non-LTS Java version seems pointless.  Non-LTS Java versions only last 6 months anyway.  Java 20 will be end-of-life in under a month from now!

Comment: Added stack trace and right now downloading Java 11 test, will return later to report what happened.

Comment: Worked perfeclty, saved my life.